# How to push to GitHub from public Windows after support for password authentication was removed?

Tags: github

I am using a public Windows computer with a public user, i.e. everybody uses the same user. In this computer I have repos that I would like to push. In the past I just used my username and password for GitHub and it worked perfectly. Now it is not possible anymore. I don't want to set up everything with the credential manager as if it were my own computer because anybody will be able to push to my account. What is the way to go in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an especially secure setup, because it allows every user to tamper with your data.  However, if it's impossible to avoid, you can generate an SSH key and place it on a flash drive (e.g., with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and a suitable `-f` argument) and then use that key to connect in the future.

You can specify the key to use either by setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, like so:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /d/id_ed25519" git push
```

or you can add a stanza to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile /d/id_ed25519
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

It is also possible to run `git config --global credential.helper "store --file=/d/credentials` and then use a token, storing the credentials on a flash drive.  However, using an SSH key would be better.